# Security Implications of Multiplication Modulo with a composite

Tags: encryption, modular-arithmetic

Cryptographic algorithms are designed using an irreducible polynomial. Irreducible polynomial generates entire field and multiplicative inverse of all elements (less zero) exist. A sample cryptographic algorithm comprises of modular operations such as Multiplication Modulo 2^32, however 2^32 is not a prime field. Since 2^32 is not a prime field, there are multiple factors of 2^32 (ie there are various values of input for which output mod 2^32 is zero). Is this transformation reversible and what are the security implications of using Multiplication Modulo with a composite number?

Comment: The question's first two sentences discuss the use of irreducible polynomials in cryptography, but seem to bear no relevance to the rest of the question. Can we remove them? Exactly which transformation is considered? If that's $x\to a\;x\bmod m$ with $0\le x<m$, hint: that transformation can be reversible even though $a$ and $m$ are composite, example: $a=15$, $m=22$. The reversibility of a transformation is well defined, its security is not; please define what you mean by "security".

Comment: @fgrieu I have studied IDEA cipher in which multiplication is done by Mul Mod (2^16) + 1, and this is done to replace zero with 2^16. This is done to ensure reversibility. I want to understand why Mul Mod 2^16 doesnot provide reversibility?

Comment: @fgrieu In the first two sentences I am trying to explain that Irreducible Polynomial generates entire field. Similarly, **Mod p** (where *p* is a prime number) also generates entire field. If **Mod n** (where *n* is a composite number and it does not generate entire field) is used in Modular Arithmetic, will **Multiplication Mod n** be a reversible operation or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation $x\to a\;x\bmod m$ with $0\le x<m$ (or $0<x<m$) is reversible if and only if $a$ is coprime with $m$. It follows that we have reversibility for all $a$ with $0<a<m$ if and only if $m$ is prime.

In the block cipher [IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Data_Encryption_Algorithm), it is used $m=2^{16}+1$ prime, thus $x\mapsto a\;x\bmod m$ with $0<x<m$ is reversible for all $a$ with $0<a<m$. Multiplication modulo $m$ is a reversible mixer for the set of $m-1$ integers $\{1,2,\dots,m-2,m-1\}$ (that is, a function with two inputs and one output in this set, so that with one input fixed, the transformation implemented by the function is reversible). That set is mapped to the set of 16-bit bitstrings $\{0,1\}^{16}$ by assimilating $m-1=2^{16}$ to the all-zero bitstring $0^{16}$, and other integers to their binary representation as a 16-bit bitstring.

We can use multiplication modulo $m$ as a reversible mixer of $k$-bit bitstrings as in IDEA if and only if $m$ is a prime of the form $m=2^k+1$, which for practicable $m$ (and as far as we know) occurs only for the five Fermat primes $F_i=2^{(2^i)}+1$ with $0\le i<5$.

For $m=2^{32}$, the transformation $x\mapsto a\;x\bmod m$ with $0\le x<m$ (or $0<x<m$) is reversible if and only if $a$ is odd. And thus, the mixer implemented by $(a,x)\mapsto a\;x\bmod m$ is not reversible. For example, with $a=2$, both $(2,2)$ and $(2,2^{31}+2)$ map to $4$.

The reversibility of a transformation is well defined, its security is not; we can't tell anything about security without a definition.

Comment: Since $2^{32}$ is not a prime number, is **Mul Mod $2^{32}$** a reversible transformation or not? As per my understanding, it is not.

Comment: @R. Sam: $x\to a\;x\bmod2^{32}$ with $0\le x<m$ (or $0<x<m$) is reversible if and only if $a$ is odd. Therefore, multiplication modulo $2^{32}$ is not a reversible mixer.

Comment: If **Mix Mode Modular Arithmetic** with **Mod $2^{32}$** is used as in **A = X + (Y x Z)** where **X, Y, Z, A** are 32-bit registers and **+** & **x** are **Addition Mod  $2^{32}$** and **Multiplication Mod $2^{32}$** respectively, is this transformation reversible? As we know that **Mul Mod $2^{32}$** is not a reversible operation. Kindly help me understand.

Comment: @R. Sam: a transformation from $\mathcal S×\mathcal S×\mathcal S→\mathcal S$ such as your $(x,y,z)↦a=(x+(y⋅z))\bmod m$ can not be reversible (that is, a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection)) if $\mathcal S$ is a finite set with more than one element (consider the size of the input and output domains). Thus when $m>1$ (prime or not), your transformation is not reversible for $0≤x<m$, $0≤y<m$, $0≤z<m$. With $y$ and $z$ fixed, it is reversible. With $y$ fixed and coprime to $m$, and $x$ fixed, it is reversible too. With $m$ prime, $y$ coprime to $m$ simplifies to $y≠0$.